# How to get business account id from shortcode in graph api?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram-api

17841404087233784?fields=media{ig_id,media_type,comments_count,like_count,shortcode}&media{shortcode=Bbi9CBQglz8}

I have tried this, but failed to get result.

Comment: Did you get any solution?